# How to filter a grid with differnet multilevel/multiple filter criteria in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a grid with large number of records. I can filter based on any one of search criteria. But not any two or more. For example, I initially filter the grid by State Names and then I want to filter a particular city based on records available for that particular state. Is it possible without any external plugins.?

I am just using inbuilt filters available in the Extjs framework.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i got the answer... Like this:

```
myStore.filter([{property: 'Data_Drive_ID',anyMatch: true,value:DsearchStr},
                    {property: 'Voice_Drive_ID',anyMatch: true,value:VsearchStr},
                    {property: 'Name',anyMatch: true,value: MsearchStr},
                    {filterFn: function(record, id){
                        if(Ext.Array.indexOf(TsearchStr, record.get("Team")) !== -1){
                            return true;
                        }    
                        return false;
                    }}
                   ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('yourGrid').getStore().filterBy(function(record) {
    return (record.get('State') == 'state1' && record.get('City') == 'city1')
});
```

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
store.filter([{
        property: 'State',
        anyMatch: true,
        value   : 'state1'
    },{
        property: 'City',
        anyMatch: true,
        value   : 'city1'
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank You. But it is working only when we enter full city name not just part of the city name. Just in case i want to filter "New York" & "New Orleans" just by entering "New" in conjunction to some other search criteria in common to both.

Comment: I have made proper changes and using it but i got a situation where i have to use above two in conjunction. Could you please help..?

Comment: sorry but I haven't understood: "I have to use above two in conjunction", can you explain to me plz